# How to verify that a parquet file on S3 is sorted

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

Another team creates a parquet file on S3 using apache-spark and they claimed the file is sorted by 'date' column. How can I verify that?

I installed parquet-tools, download the file from S3 and save it as 'f1.parquet', then use: 
parquet-tools meta f1.parquet
It shows the schema but I don't see anything that mentions the data is sorted on 'date' column.